# standard separator between datablocks in a data stream?

Tags: ascii, control-characters

I have several TSV tables (for any characters below ASCII 32 only common characters are contained, such as '\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\e'). I'd like to put them into a single stream. I think that ASCII control characters can be used to separate them. But I am not sure which ASCII control character (other than the ones already used as shown above) is standard for this purpose. Does anybody know what is the standard?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of standards for what you suggest.

Many protocols use envelopes with a count for what is to follow (TCP) or an index with offsets and lengths (tar, zip) or an arbitrary unique separator that is defined in the header (multipart MIME). There are some that are a simple series like yours but that have formatting that makes item separation obvious (XML element stream [which differs from a document because it has no root element]).

Is the idea that you might not know from the start how many tables and/or rows there are? (That is the use case for XML element streams.)

␀ seems reasonable, perhaps with final extra ␀ to mark the end of the stream (DOS/Windows program environment block).

␊ making an empty line also seems reasonable (like in SMTP).

␚(^Z) is a common file terminator from the days of CP/M and DOS.

Comment: NUL could be reasonable. `FS (file separator)` is an alternative. The latter makes more sense by its name? How was it used in the old days? XML should be avoided as I want to avoid complexity associated with it. Without XML, I can just use awk or any other simple tools. With it, I will have to use an XML parser, which can be an overkill in many cases. Also, I can guarantee only '\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\e' from control chars are used in my data. It should be possible for me to select a reasonable separator to denote different files in a stream.